# how many copies of tp53 (p53) gene do we have?

Tags: gene

I just started studying biology so I almost have no knowledge.

I learned about the tp53 gene and I just wanted to know how many copies of tp53 gene we have?

Answer (score 1):

Humans have one copy of the p53 gene per set of chromosomes along with most other mammals (a notable exception being elephants with 20)[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://www.nature.com/news/how-elephants-avoid-cancer-1.18534). Since it is located on an autosome (chromosome 17), each parent gives one copy of the gene[<sup>[2]</sup>](http://may2017.archive.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Gene/Summary?db=core;g=ENSG00000141510;r=17:7661779-7687550). Meaning two copies per human cell (and 40 per elephant cell).

---

A little extra information on p53 and the effects of only having 2 copies:

Since humans only have two copies per cell and p53 forms a homo-tetramer, it only takes one mutated copy to lose functionality.[<sup>[3]</sup>](https://www.nature.com/articles/1207396) This is because p53 needs to tetramerize to function, meaning only 1 out of 16 p53 proteins are effective if one copy is mutated (2<sup>4</sup> possibilities and only 1 combination has 0 mutated copies, ~6% are functional). This makes p53 a rare human tumor-suppressor gene with dominant negative mutations.

But with elephants, the more copies they have, the less and less one mutation affects the amount of functional p53. ($\bigl( \frac {39}{40}\bigr)$<sup>4</sup> probability of having a functional tetramer = 90% functional, which is very high)